# Converting an Ember-Data RecordArray to an Ember Array

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am getting some records back as a `RecordArray` or a `FilteredRecordArray` and I'd like to convert this to an array of Ember objects (or maybe just POJO objects). I had thought maybe I could do the following:

```
emberDataRecords.map( item => {
  return Ember.Object.create( JSON.stringify(item) );
});
```

but it appears the Ember-Data structure is circular and so JSON falls over. Anyway, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if it's what you are searching for but there is a `toArray()` method that can be executed on every `Enumerable` object. `RecordArray` is `enumerable`, therefore the result is an Array of `DS.Model` objects. Reference here http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_toArray

Comment: Thanks, the biggest problem for me though has been getting the ED objects converted from model objects to just Ember objects. This may be a bad idea anyway; the primary motivation had been to find a way to do full property reflection on the ED object (which Ember.keys() does not support). Right now I'm heading in a different design direction which gets around the reflection requirement.